# What's the word for "autosuggestion" when it's done by someone else?

Tags: single-word-requests

**autosuggestion**
n. influencing one's attitudes or behavior through self-suggestion

What's the word if it's someone else doing the suggestion, as often happens in cultish 'brainwashing'? E.g., a group of people meditates. As the leader lulls them into a semi-awake state, he drops ideas into their subconscious mind. Then they begin to see things as suggested.

Comment: How about just plain "suggestion"?

Comment: @Lawrence, why didn't I think of that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Manipulate**

from google:

> "control or influence (a person or situation) cleverly or
>   unscrupulously."

example:

> the masses were deceived and manipulated by a tiny group"

Answer (score 2):

***[Indoctrination](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/indoctrination)*** comes to mind:

> - teaching someone to accept doctrines uncritically

though ***brainwashing*** also fits:

> - forcible indoctrination into a new set of attitudes and beliefs

The Free Dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Insinuate. Reference : [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/insinuate)

Answer (score 0):

Consider **mental conditioning**.

> *Cult brainwashing vs. mental conditioning* [Ex Family](http://www.exfamily.org/chatbbs/genx/archives2/15328.htm)
>
> *The **mind control and mental conditioning** in a cult is a deplorable way to govern a society* [An Unusual Journey: My Life in a Cult](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=Wm2nAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA65&lpg=PA65&dq=mental+conditioning+cult&source=bl&ots=NCNKrevca0&sig=4vb4insVfAdUrV7nqxursdk_Ze4&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CE4Q6AEwBmoVChMIw8zg2tfTyAIVhTYaCh2MEg4Z#v=onepage&q=mental%20conditioning%20cult&f=false)